# Don't escape expression value in HTML attribute of Polymer component

Tags: polymer

I have a Polymer component with access to an {{object}} that has several values (like {{object.id}}, {{object.title}}, and so forth.

Now, this..

`<a href="#">{{object.title}}</a>`

.. works just fine (renders a link with the output from object.title).

This, however..

`<a href="/posts/{{object.id}}">{{object.title}}</a>`

Renders HTML that looks like this:

`<a href="/posts/%7B%7Bpost.id%7D%7D">Title</a>`

As you can see, the post value is escaped. To test whether this was a matter of expression performing unexpectedly, I also tried populating a non-`href` attribute (i.e. `data-test="{{post.id}}"`) which works just fine -- `href` specifically gives unexpected results.

Perhaps I'm just not doing this in a very "Polymeric" way -- is there a proper way to use a Polymer expression's value in an HTML `href` attribute?

**EDIT:** Thanks, @Timo for the solution to this problem - an underscore before the attribute:

```
<a _href="/posts/{{object.id}}">{{object.title}}</a>
```

Comment: I cannot see any issue in your code, could you please post more code, or better providing a running demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the underscored attribute **_href** in order to have Polymer resolve the bindings:

```
<a _href="/posts/{{object.id}}">{{object.title}}</a>
```

Polymer will then automatically resolve the object.id binding and set the correct href attribute

Comment: Bingo -- thanks, Timo D! Is there any documentation on this? I haven't seen this syntax in any of the documentation so far.

Comment: Well, I learnt about this through a Polymer warning that sent me here: https://www.dartlang.org/polymer/reference/error-messages/#polymer_28 and that will link you to this small section of the Polymer documentation: https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-compat.html#binding-to-attributes